# Upload image to a web site automatically

Tags: image, flash, upload, web, automation

I'm looking for a solution to be able to upload images to a web site without the need to fill the form myself.  The site in question uses a flash button with triggers the file selection on my computer and then uploads my selected files on the web page.  Is there any way I can automate this process ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proxy/web debugger such as fiddler2, see what the http transaction looks like for a single file upload and then write an app to do that same for your list of images.